# How to add multiple hyperlinks to an xlsx cell using GemBox.Spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm creating an Excel report using GemBox.Spreadsheet, but having trouble getting multiple hyperlinks to appear in the same cell. Below is the code:

```
cell = sheet.Range[rowId, colId++];
foreach (var doc in item.Documents)
{
    var h = sheet.HyperLinks.Add(cell);
    h.Type = ExcelHyperLinkType.Url;
    h.Address = doc.Url.Contains("://") ? doc.Url : @"http://" + doc.Url;
    h.TextToDisplay = doc.UrlWords;
}
```

When I look at the results, only the last link appears.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I was fearing. Thanks, Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible to accomplish in Excel files. Internally, Excel files store hyperlinks outside the cell and they will only contain a reference to an associated cell.

Also, another way that hyperlinks can be defined is with HYPERLINK formula, but even with that approach you cannot achieve your requirement.

Just as a side not, are you sure that you're using GemBox.Spreadsheet?
The [`ExcelCell.Hyperlink`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/T_GemBox_Spreadsheet_SpreadsheetHyperlink.htm) property does not have `Add` method. See the [Excel cell hyperlinks](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-cell-hyperlinks/207) example.

Comment: Nope, not sure at all. Legacy code that references the GemBox dll.